# Storing sensitive data in Supabase public schema?

Tags: postgresql, supabase

Supabase uses a `public` schema in Postgres that exposes your schema to their REST API and GraphQL endpoints.

I understand that RLS policies can be set so that, for instance, a user can only see their own data and no one elses.

But let's say sensitive information is stored in a public schema's table as well, something like encrypted third party refresh/access tokens or the like. For example, let's just say a table called `tokens`. With an RLS policy, the user can only access their own tokens, that makes sense.

But the schema is still public, meaning, malicious actors now know what to look for in terms of the shape of the data/database design.

Am I being paranoid that this schema is public and "not obscure", or is this lack of "security through obscurity" not a problem since the data itself is protected by RLS?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't expose the API? I'm missing how you expect to provide access to the tables through an API while simultaneously concealing the existence of those tables.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Supabase automatically exposes a REST API and GraphQL endpoint, however, I'm not using either. I'm connecting directly to the Postgres instance. And as far as I know, there is no way to disable the rest/graphql endpoints.